# Is PurchaseDate of AppReceipt in UTC or local time?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal

In UWP Windows 10 apps, we can get the purchase date of the app or an add-on. [(Documenation here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases#appreceipt)

```
var receipt = await CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync();
```

But no were it's mentioned the date is in UTC or local user time! 
Thanks.

Comment: Nor do I have any time for you question.

Comment: @RichardSchneider You may know the answer from a previous similar situation, or you may know it without having to actually try it. Soo.. go breath some fresh air ;)

Comment: OP, you originally said "I've no time"; which is why I have no time to look at the question.

Comment: @RichardSchneider I said I have no time because the app is published and there is no time to try and test, publish the app, wait for store certification etc to finally see how it works. Anyway the problem is fixed, and apparently UWP apps are not your field of interest. good luck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the receipt you will see that the date has 'Z' at the end:

> PurchaseDate="2015-12-14T19:37:05.692Z"

This means that it's UTC time. Some references: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1728437/2681948), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/833143/2681948).

Comment: Thank you very much <3 @Romasz