# DateTime timestamp is changing when saving

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have two types of dates that are set programmatically.

```
initialDate = 06/23/2020 00:00:00

finalDate = 06/23/2020 23:59:59
```

These dates are set programmatically like:

```
var initialDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(_ff).Add(startTimeSpan);
var finalDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(_ff).Add(endTimeSpan)
```

When saving this to db, the timestamp is changed.

The dates become like this:

```
initialDate = 06/23/2020 04:00:00.000
finalDate = 06/24/2020 03:59:59.999
```

How can I prevent this from happening in C#?

Comment: Tip: Don't just put `ES db` without explaining what it is -- people will be hard pressed in guessing what is stands for. In this case, I am going to assume it's `Elasticsearch` though not too sure. Whatever the case, have you checked your DB's timezone setting? I see the UTC timestamp getting adjusted to a GMT+4 timezone.

Comment: I want it to take only the datime I am passing. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the timezone of your dates ?

Comment: GMT +4 is the timezone

Comment: Yes it was helpful. But I ignored the timezone using DateOffset

Comment: Fantastic. You can add that as an answer or update your question with the findings. It ll be helpful to someone. Hope you don't mind to approve my answer if it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, your timezone is `GMT +4`. That's why `4hours` are added to your date.

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified) and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html)

It's best to keep `UTC` formats in the index. And apply timezone settings at the query time.

To query the data:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "initialDate": {
        "time_zone": "+04:00",        
        "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00", 
          //value you are providing as input from your timezone, hence I am adding +04
        "lte": "now"                  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#range-query-time-zone)

> time_zone (Optional, string) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) offset
> or IANA time zone used to convert date values in the query to UTC.

**EDIT:**

Apart from the internals, you want to see the date that you provide. You can do that by using timezone format in the mapping.

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

**Mapping:** - `PUT http://host:port/indexName/_mapping`

```
timestamp1{
"type": "date_nanos",
"ignore_malformed": true,
"format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
}
```

**Post:** `POST http://host:port/indexName/_doc`

```
{
    "timestamp1":"2020-12-31T16:00:00Z",
    "key":"1"
}
```

**Search:** `GET http://host:port/indexName/_search`

```
 "_source": {
        "timestamp1": "2020-12-31T16:00:00Z",
        "key": "1"
    }
```

But internally this date will be stored as milliseconds and retrieval time it uses the string you provided at the time of index.

[More format options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in)

Comment: What modifications do I need to make?

Comment: No. but why doesn't it save the datetime that I am providing? Also, display same datetime on Kibana.

Comment: I am not understanding where do I set the Mapping, timestamp1 ?

Comment: I set that on my test index. [Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) - added syntax too

Comment: But it my case, I have an object in C#. How do I do that?
The mapping takes place from my class.

Comment: You can't do that via `C#`. I suggest you to understand `elasticsearch`. `c#` is a client to access data stored in `elasticsearch`.

Comment: But I am storing the datetime from c#. I want it to save the exact datetime in ES.

Comment: Can you show me the mapping of `initialDate` by executing `http://host:port/indexName/_mapping`. I can help if there is a way with this.

Comment: `"initialDate":{"type":"date"},"finalDate":{"type":"date"},` Here you are.

Comment: You need to pass the date as the way I mentioned in the answer. It will work from c#. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: How can I modify that from c# ?

Comment: [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728404/date-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz) It will help you